# Entity Framework - Avoiding child duplicates if they are not persited yet

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

Actually I use DbContext, but I just tested it with ObjectContext as well.

```
// Engine 1
Engine engine = new Engine();
Manufacturer manufacturer = new Manufacturer();

engine.Manufacturer = manufacturer;

// Engine 2
engine = new Engine();
engine.Manufacturer = manufacturer // Engine 2 has the same manufacturer like Engine 1

context.SaveChanges();
```

I use identity columns (int), where new IDs are generated. In debug mode I see that the ID for engine is "0". Well, if I implement context.SaveChanges right after the Engine 1 block, the new manufacturer is being saved to DB. With EntityKey or Any check, I can reference the new manufacturer to Engine 2 without any problems. But without immediate SaveChanges(), two entries of same manufacturer are being saved to DB (the code above). Is EF unable to reference internally like normal objects? As you see above, manufacturer is one and the same object, so I wonder if it's possible to obtain a successfull insert without pre-save the child/manufacturer.

EDIT: I think I found the problem

```
MachineEntities context = new MachineEntities();
        context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;

        // Engine 1
        Engine engine1 = new Engine();
        engine1.Name = "engine1";

        Manufacturer manufacturer = new Manufacturer();
        manufacturer.Name = "manufacturer1";

        engine1.Manufacturer = manufacturer;

        // Engine 2
        Engine engine2 = new Engine();
        engine2.Name = "engine2";

        manufacturer = new Manufacturer();
        manufacturer.Name = "manufacturer1";

        engine2.Manufacturer = manufacturer;


        // Add Engine 1

        if (context.Manufacturers.Any(m => m.Name == engine1.Manufacturer.Name))
        {
            // The manufacturer's name is identical, so use the one in the context instead the assigned one.
            engine1.Manufacturer = context.Manufacturers.Single(m => m.Name == engine1.Manufacturer.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            // The manufacturer is not known, add it to the context
            context.Set<Manufacturer>().Add(engine1.Manufacturer);
        }

        // Add Engine 2


        if (context.Manufacturers.Any(m => m.Name == engine1.Manufacturer.Name))
        {
            // The manufacturer's name is identical, so use the one in the context instead the assigned one.
            engine2.Manufacturer = context.Manufacturers.Single(m => m.Name == engine2.Manufacturer.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Manufacturers.Add(engine2.Manufacturer);
        }

        context.SaveChanges();

        context.Dispose();
```

"Any" or any comparison won't give me any results. It only gives me those entities, which are already persisted in DB, but not the fresh new added ones. So it's duplicated. The local ones are ignored as I see in debugger, and the one in "Result View" are the one, where the command is executed against. So the new added entities are located in "Manufacturers.Local".

Comment: You never add the `engine` to your context. Have you customized the Entity Framework objects' code in order to make this work, or did you just strip those lines of code out for the purpose of this example? Showing how the objects get added may help you to get a good answer.

Comment: no need to add it in ObjectContext, but a must in DbContext. It really adds it automatically.

Comment: That's not the standard Entity Framework behavior. You may want to check your constructors for custom code, because `new Engine()` should not automatically add the engine to your context.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: No joke. If you add manufacturer to any engine object, it's added. Maybe the setter has some internal code and the context can track globally. Strange? Yes, but true. For example a DLL holds the data access part(+EF). An external developer needs access to the data objects and use the distributed POCO parts. In my case he would create a new Engine, add the new manufacturer. All I need in the data DLL is a method with using SaveChanges only as single code line.That's not logical, but I already have seen that. If you add it to the context 2 identical engines will be in database

Comment: Again, the behavior you're describing would only occur if one of the related objects has already somehow been tied to the context. The only way for the Entity Framework to track the context globally is if the Framework-generated code has been specifically modified to make that happen. I notice that you don't show how the context is being created. What code happens before this that you're not showing? What happens if you try to run your code without creating a context first? Try connecting LINQPad to your context and running the code you posted. Does the same thing happen?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, you are right. In a former version, entites were copied leading to this behaviour.

Comment: If you had shown the code you are actually using from the beginning instead of a torso which hasn't much to do with your real code, your question would have been answered after 5 minutes from 10 people. StriplingWarrior did ask you in the very first comment if you stripped out any lines of code, didn't he? Never mind, just a tip for the next question to be precise with the code you show. Or at least write above your question: "This is a game. Here is some code which has the following error. Please guess what are the pieces of code I have hidden which make this error happen!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried the following:

```
var a1 = new Activity{WorkflowId = 1, Title = "test"};
var a2 = new Activity{WorkflowId = 1, Title = "test2"};
var d = new WorkflowDisplay{WorkflowId = 1, Title = "Test"};
a1.WorkflowDisplay = d;
a2.WorkflowDisplay = d;
// Any of the next three lines can be commented out, but if
// they are all commented, nothing happens.
AddToWorkflowDisplays(d);
AddToActivities(a1);
AddToActivities(a2);
SaveChanges();
```

... and I only saw a single `WorkflowDisplay` added. So I'm pretty sure this has something to do with your specific implementation. Have you overridden the `GetHashCode` or `Equals` methods of any of your entities, or done any similar sort of customization of the auto-generated code?

Comment: StriplingWarrior, I use identity column, the Id isn't available prior to SaveChanges. With your code it works because you set the Id explicitly.

Comment: @Vogt: Look again. I'm setting the WorkflowId because that happens to be required in my model, but the reference I'm editing is the one between an `Activity` and a `WorkflowDisplay`. I'm not explicitly setting the identities of any of these objects.

Comment: any special instructions in method 'AddToWorkflowDiplays'?

Comment: @Vogt: Entity Framework added that for me. It just calls `AddObject("WorkflowDisplays", arg)`. (I'm running this code in LINQPad, so it's in the scope of the Entity Context. For clarity, you could change this to `context.AddToWorkflowDisplays(d)`.)